# Dictionary to list kdb

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to setup a function that takes a nested dictionary and replaces each dictionary
with a pair of lists:

For example:

```
$ x:`a`b!(`c`e!20 30;`h`g!(4;`i`j!26 7))    

$ dict2List d
(`a`b;((`c`e;20 30);(`h`g;(4;(`i`j;26 7)))))
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just unwrapping dictionaries with (key;value):

```
q)f:{:$[99h=type x;(key x;.z.s each value x);x]}
q)d:`a`b!(`c`e!20 30;`h`g!(4;`i`j!26 7))
q)f d
(`a`b;((`c`e;20 30j);(`h`g;(4j;(`i`j;26 7j)))))
```

Answer (score -1):

q)f:{[x] value ssr["(",.Q.s1[x],")";"!";";"]}
q)f[x]
`a`b
(`c`e;20 30;`h`g;(4;`i`j;26 7))